# Hessian estimates of eigenfunctions without Bochner

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Consider the Dirichlet eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of Laplacian on $\Omega$, that are, the $\lambda_i>0$ and $\phi_i\in H^{1}_0(\Omega)$ such that $-\Delta \phi_i=\lambda_i\phi_i$.

In general the hessian estimates of $\phi_i$ can be done by Bochner formula and suitable bounds on Ricci curvature and mean curvature of $\partial \Omega$ (assume smoothness of the boundary).

What can we do except for this? Is there any precise bounds(or asymptotics) on Hessian of $\phi_i$ without Bochner, or even without curvature bounds? For example, is

$$
\left|\int_{\Omega}|\mathrm{Hess}_{\phi_i}|^2d\mathrm{Vol}_g-\lambda_i^2\right|\le C\lambda_i+o(\lambda_i)
$$
possible? What could be a counterexample if not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine that the answer to this question would hinge rather critically on what the constant $C$ is permitted to depend on, and similarly how uniform the decay rate in the $o()$ notation is required to be.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you for the suggestion, let's say that C depends on dimension $n$, the geometry of $\Omega$(not sure), and possibly also the Ricci lower bound $K$. I actually have read one of your paper which says that the $L^2$ lower bound of normal derivative on the boundary is related to the (non-)presence trapped geodesics, is this also a factor to consider here? For uniform rate, I am not sure could you say something in both cases?